# Workday integration error - The query returned too many results

Tags: integration, erp, workday-api

I am new to Workday HCM, running an integration and getting following error. Can anybody give me direction on troubleshoot this issue or any know solution to this.

An Error occurred when processing the query. The query returned too many results.. Cause: com.workday.exceptions.EndUserException: An Error occurred when processing the query. The query returned too many results.

*Error - An Error occurred when processing the query

Cause - com.workday.exceptions.EndUserException*

[image]

I did some more investigation and able narrow down the problem area  - the problem is related to 'Business Process Transactions' data source.

Comment: How many records are you returning? There is a limit on the size of the records returned in an integration - especially if it is a non-studio integration

Comment: @alpharomeo Do you know where size of records is defined in workday?

Comment: If this is re RAAS / Webservices / Integration then look for Integration and webservices limit. What do you mean by Size of Records? You mean for a field?